# How can I help my boss better organize 3 small teams with a common goal?

Tags: project-management

I work in an aircraft engine test facility. We have 3 or 4 (depending on how you look at it) small teams in our group and each of us have clear roles and tasks to complete. During a test campaign, certain unexpected and expected issues come up and one or more of the teams need to address them before we can continue testing an engine.

Currently, we use outlook with daily, hand written email updates sent to about 40 people. Sometimes people forget, sometimes they aren't complete and most of the time they get lost in the 20-30 other emails we get per day. We also have 2 and sometimes 3 different shifts in one day and the information doesn't always get passed between shifts.

I consider myself quite tech-savvy and was hoping to find a system/software/tool that could help us log tasks that need to be completed before moving forward.

What I would like is a system where, when an issue arises, the person/people concerned would log the issue, and everyone else would be able to see that there is an issue preventing us from moving forward.

The way I see it is before we start setting up to run the engine, we would check the "system" to see if there are any outstanding issues, who is responsible for them, how long they will take and whether or not they are truly preventing us from carrying on.

Most tools out there seem to focus on software development, and that is not what I am looking for. This is about managing teams with respect to a facility and hardware/instrumentation.

Does anyone know of anything that might work for us? My alternative is to develop something in-house but I don't want to waste time if something solid already exists.

Comment: A ticketing system with a kanban board could help you, Atlassian Jira and Iguana can do this.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, Matthew! Could you please [edit] your post and add a bullet-point list of features the software would need – plus what OS(es) it should run on, and what your price margin would be? That would help us a lot recommending what really meets your needs. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a straightforward issue tracker. See [our questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracker) and/or Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ATLASSIAN JIRA` or `BUGZILLA`.

According to Atlassian, `Jira` is used for issue tracking and project management by over 75,000 customers in 122 countries. Many large organizations like *Fedora Commons, Hibernate, Twitter, Skype Technologies, NASA, the United States Department of Defense and The Apache Software Foundation* uses both `Jira` and `Bugzilla`. `Jira` includes tools allowing migration from competitor `Bugzilla`.

`Jira` is offered in three packages and is written in Java and uses Pico's inversion of control container, Apache OFBiz entity engine, and WebWork 1 technology stack. For remote procedure calls (RPC), Jira supports REST, SOAP, and XML-RPC. Jira integrates with source control programs such as *Clearcase, Concurrent Versions System (CVS), Git, Mercurial, Perforce, Subversion and Team Foundation Server*. It ships with various translations including English, French, German, Japanese, and Spanish.

`Jira` supports the Networked Help Desk API for sharing customer support tickets with other issue tracking systems.

More information is available here:
https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/agile

Comment: Have had experience using Jira in several situations (company with 1000 employees, as well as a tiny start-up), and it's definitely one of the nicer ones to use. For a small team of this size, especially if you can host it locally, it's well worth the money (one time $10 payment). It's not necessarily tied to software development. I've seen it used for all sorts of tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Use Trello.com
It's free to use it, very simple and intuitive.

Comment: Takes about 15mn to get the hang of it, works great with teams...  can't second that recommendation enough :-)